# Entity Framework, Relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have following entities:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
}
public class Tenant : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual Nullable<long> SQLDatabaseId { get; set; }
    public virtual SQLDatabase SQLDatabase { get; set; }
    public virtual Nullable<long> StorageAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual StorageAccount StorageAccount { get; set; }
}
public class SQLDatabase : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual long TenantId { get; set; }        
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
public class StorageAccount : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual long TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

And in **OnModelCreating** with fulent API

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SQLDatabase>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Tenant);
modelBuilder.Entity<StorageAccount>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Tenant);
```

Now when I run the project it creates database with strange way

It creates a one to one relation from Tenant to SQLDatabase which is OK, but when I see that in SSMS, this relationship is from Tenant.Id to SQLDatabase.Id

Which isn't true. A tenant is mandatory for creating SQL database and Storage Account and also that the relationship is 1:1 in either case.

Comment: you do not need `public virtual Nullable<long> SQLDatabaseId { get; set; }` and `public virtual Nullable<long> StorageAccountId { get; set; }` if you want *one-to-one* relationship

Comment: @Adil Mammadov, Removed those properties from Tenant Entities and still relationship remains from Tenant.Id to SQLDatabase.Id

Comment: Are you updating database after changing configurations?

Comment: I have this... Database.SetInitializer<RMContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<RMContext>()); in my Global.asax in Application_Start just to quickly check the database. which drops and creates it.

Comment: It should work as expected now. I paid attention now, be sure to remove `public virtual long TenantId { get; set; }` properties also. You do not need any foreign key, they should be bound via primary keys.

Comment: @Adil Mammadov I have already removed those properties from Tenant Entity. And also removed TenantId  from SQLDatabase and StorageAccount Entity. Yet no success. Remains same relationship 1:1 but on wrong columns Id:Id instead of Id:TenantId

Comment: But you do not have `TennatId` property. If they are bound *Id:Id* then everything is working as expected. I am stating again, in *one-to-one* relationships they should be bound via primary keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify which is *Principal* and which is *Dependent*. Try follwoing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SQLDatabase>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Tenant)
    .WithRequiredDependent(m => m.SQLDatabase);
modelBuilder.Entity<StorageAccount>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Tenant)
    .WithRequiredDependent(m => m.StorageAccount);
```

Comment: It created 2 relationship.... 1. Tenant.Id -> SQLDatabase.Id & 2. SQLDatabase.Id -> Tenants.SQLDatabase_Id 
The first relationship is not correct!

Comment: no change, It remains as it is.Actually it converted to what was originally...
See updated question....